# What does the "automatically adjusts font requires using a dynamic type text style" warning mean?

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode8

I am getting the following warning:

> "automatically adjusts font requires using a dynamic type text style"

[image: Screenshot added]

Which I can not get rid of the warning is on `main.storyboard`.

I have checked every `UILabel` in the `Identity Inspector` to make sure the **"Automatically Adjusts Font"** is unchecked.

Comment: I suspect "automatically adjusts font requires using a dynamic type text style", probably to adjust it dynamically.

Comment: You want to use a dynamic font ("Body", "Headline", "Subhead"), OR more likely, turn off `Automatically Adjusts Font` and turn on `Autoshrink`.

Comment: How do you understand which of the dozens of storyboards and then of the dozens of labels, is causing the issue when the warning is NOT clickable?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It seems to have been a bug in Xcode. This is what I did to fix it:

1. Change the font in the label that showed the error, to a dynamic type, as suggested
2. Select check box for "Automatically Adjusts Font"
3. Build and run the project (the error disappears)
4. Uncheck the "Automatically Adjusts Font" box
5. Change the font back to the previous setting that caused the error
6. Rebuild the project

The error is still gone.

Comment: I agree. Double and triple checked my files and even checked XML/source - it was not there yet XCode insists it is (even after a "clean"). How annoying.

Comment: `I changed the font in the label that showed the error, to a dynamic type,`-- I can't see any option that looks like it would be a `dynamic type` in the fonts. Suggestions?

Comment: I am now using the system font.  I was using a custom font in some of the labels, which caused the problem.  If you google dynamic fonts in Xcode, you may be able to find a list of other fonts which are dynamic.  A little research goes a long way.  Good luck.

Comment: Hi @K.Law thanks for answer but **Xcode** generate several same warning and all of the views are in the Intro.storyboard. When I clicked warning, Xcode just show the **Storyboard** not a spesific item.

Answer (score 63):

1. Open your storyboard as Source Code
2. Search for key "adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory"
3. Check which object has this option and uncheck Dynamic Type checkbox from interface builder.

Comment: In my case, I have this warning, but the `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory` key doesn't appear in the Source Code.

Comment: I think it works now (Xcode 11) to just click on the warning and it selects the offending label. (So you can avoid the source code steps)

Comment: @ChrisPrince, did you wind up solving that?

Answer (score 44):

I just changed Text style to **Body** & Warning vanishes.

It's Just because
it is dynamic type textStyle

See list of predefined supported  dynamic type textStyle  -

[image]

Comment: Changing it to `body` seems to make it lose the ability to be bolded text.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such.

Comment: Changing it to body will reset font size

Answer (score 32):

I had the same problem. Even after I opened the storyboard as source and removed the "adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory" key, saved and cleaned the project it would still show.

So then I:

1. Cleaned the project
2. Closed Xcode
3. Deleted the derived data folder contents
4. Re-Opened Xcode and rebuilt

It was gone. :)

Comment: Step 1: press ⇧⌥⌘K to clean the project and derived data. Omit step 3.

Comment: hmmm, ⇧⌥⌘K cleans the build folder inside the app's derivedData. But it does not deletes the whole derivedData folder. Is that enough? Or we do the usual "xCode Voodoo Dance" as described above :D

Comment: Voodoo Dance worked for me. I had the same issue and for deprecated Push Segues as well. I manually changed every segue and label but warnings did not go away. Removing the DerivedData folder fixed it.

Answer (score 20):

If the "Automatically adjusts font" box is checked with a non dynamic font this warning will appear. Either uncheck the box on the offending label or use a dynamic font type.

[image]

Comment: In my case, this box is unchecked, but I am getting the warning.

Comment: How can you determine if your font is "non-dynamic"?

Comment: @user664939 Non-dynamic fonts are able to change family and style.
Dynamic fonts are not able to change family and style. It will get default as per size.
you can set family and style from storyboard -> attribute inspector -> font.

Comment: @user664939: instead of selecting a specific font, you select a font "type". Click the boxed "T" in the Font dropdown. In the window that opens, click the arrows to the right of that Font dropdown. Choose a "Text Style" from the list at the bottom. See the [HIG's Visual Design, Typography section](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/typography/) for info on point sizes, etc, related to each text style.

Answer (score 18):

1. Open your storyboard, right click storyboard in file navigator.

[image]

2. Search for (command F) and delete instances of
   `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory="YES"`

Comment: In my Xcode (11.1), there is no "Automatically adjusts font" box. I tried everything else, nothing worked, except this - with 0 votes. Thx

Comment: The adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory are for UITextField issues and adjustsFontSizeToFit for UILabel issues

Answer (score 5):

In the Storyboard, after **uncheck** every "Automatically Adjusts Font" in the **Attributes Inspector**, run **shift + command + K** and then build your project again. This should clean your project and remove the warning.

Answer (score 4):

## Xcode 11+:

1. **Right-Click** the storyboard that's having this issue (Check Issue Navigator if you don't know which)
2. Go to the ***Open As*** option and select ***Source Code***
3. Replace every **adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO"** with **adjustsFontSizeToFit="YES"**
4. Run your application
5. Watch the warning go away (And even if you undo step 3)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error for automatic adjusting on a button. But I could not find "Automatic Adjust Font" checkbox on right panel. Get rid of warning by going to source code of .storyboard and deleting "adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory" properties on problematic button solved my problem.